# Find N unique values inside ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have an example dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, TRUE), "Z", "Z"), 
                 b = c(rnorm(10), NA, NA))
```

and I'm trying to do some simple plotting and add some color.  I can do this easily knowing how many `a` values there will be before I even plot:

```
library(randomcoloR)

df %>%
    filter(!is.na(b)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x = a, y = b),
             fill = randomColor(5),
             stat = "summary", 
             fun.y = "mean")
```

But what if I don't know how many `a` values there will be?  How can get the number of unique `a` inline *inside* the `geom_xxx` statement?

Using `n_distinct(a)` does not work and provides the error

```
df %>%
    filter(!is.na(b)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x = a, y = b),
             fill = randomColor(n_distinct(a)),
             stat = "summary", 
             fun.y = "mean")
```

> Error in n_distinct_multi(list(...), na.rm) : object 'a' not found

Using `uniqueN()` from `data.table` does not work and provides the error:

```
library(data.table)

df %>%
    filter(!is.na(b)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x = a, y = b),
             fill = randomColor(uniqueN(a)),
             stat = "summary", 
             fun.y = "mean")
```

> Error in uniqueN(a) : object 'a' not found

Using `unique(a) %>% length()` does not work, either, and provides the same error immediately above.

Can I find inline the number of unique `a` values inside a `geom_xxx` statement?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious, here.

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the data frame into an anonymous function:

```
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(b)) %>%
  (function(df) ({
    ggplot(df) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = a, y = b),
               fill = randomColor(length(unique(df$a))),
               stat = "summary",
               fun.y = "mean")
    }))
```